# How to avoid code duplication in a Puppet array?

Tags: arrays, puppet, code-duplication

**Aim**

At the company there is a script that is able to start a JAR file. Most of these JAR files need to be started twice and some of them three times. Today an array has been created in order to start JARs multiple times. It works as expected, but the question is how to avoid code duplication in a Puppet array?

**Array**

```
$variables [
  'JAR_0',
  'JAR_0',
  'JAR_0',
  'JAR_1',
  'JAR_1',
  'JAR_1',
  'JAR_2',
  'JAR_2',
  'JAR_2',
  'JAR_3',
  'JAR_3',
  'JAR_4',
  'JAR_4',
  'JAR_5',
  'JAR_5',
  'JAR_6',
  'JAR_6',
  'JAR_6',
  'JAR_7',
  'JAR_7',
  'JAR_8',
  'JAR_8',
  'JAR_8',
  'JAR_9',
  'JAR_9',
  'JAR_9'
]
```

**For loop**

```
<% @variables.each do |variable| -%>
    hello <%= variable %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a map instead, like:

```
$variables = {
  'JAR_0' => 3,
  'JAR_1' => 2,
  'JAR_2' => 2,
  'JAR_3' => 3
}
```

Then in the template you'd have a loop like this

```
<% @variables.keys.each do |k| -%>
  <% @variables[k].to_i.times do -%>
    hello <%= k %>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: It is good idea to use Hash in ruby (+1), but not sure OP need always output with same sequence or not.  maybe it needs `variables = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new`